# Bootstrap centered-processing-modal on a DIV/Form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please see this: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/centered-processing-modal

It is a modal for letting the user know that something is going on in the backend, so please wait. How can I have this only on a form/div and not the whole page in Bootstrap3?

Thanks for helping

Comment: What do you want actually? Do you want the rotating thing to show up covering part of the page?

Comment: there is a form, I want the same modal comes for the form only, and not the whole page, centered on the form, responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it as they did it, you can use the chrome inspector for that, but i'll describe the technique for you.

1) Create a div (or any element that you want, as long as if its not a block element you change its display to block) inside a container, in this case your form or a div containing that form.

2) Set the position of that container as `relative` and the modal position to `absolute`, if you don't set the parent position to relative, the modal will be relative to the body tag.

3) Set a fixed widht and height for your modal, lets say `200px` for both, then add a top and a left property for the modal of 50%, this will center your element top-left corner relative to its parent, since you want the center of the element in the middle and not the corner, you need to do an offset adjustment, by moving up and left half its size, for this you'll use `margin-top: -100px;` and `margin-left:-100px;` which is the negative of widht/2 and height/2

Here is how your **html** should look like:

```
<div class="container">
 <!-- your form here -->
 <div class="custom-modal">
   <!-- loading gif here -->
 </div>
</div>
```

And here is how your **css** should look like:

```
.container{
  position:relative; 
}
.custom-modal {
 width: 200px!important; /* Use !important in case you want to override another val*/
 height: 200px;
 position: absolute; /*You can use fixed too*/
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: -100px;
 margin-left: -100px;
 display:none; /* You want it to be hidden, and show it using jquery*/
}
```

Now, you should set it as hidden, and when do your ajax request, you can set its visibility back with javascript.

---

**Jquery** example

```
// Store your modal object in a variable

var $myModal = $('.custom-modal');

// On ajax call or any event call this

$myModal.fadeIn();

// When your ajax call is done, then hide it again on the callback

$myModal.fadeOut();
```

Comment: This is not centered, this might be some css issues caused by using the same .modal class as bootstrap does

Comment: in this way we need to have the modal div on our each form, how this could be only pasted once in the script somewhere like header and then use it on every form/div? then we could activate it with jQuery like: $myCustomModal('#DIV_ID_NAME', show/hide);

Comment: another thing, would you please have it without .modal class and with some custom classes which bootstrap doesn't work with?

Comment: I've edited the class name, if you want to override a property from the bootstrap modal class or any other css lib you might be using, add    "!important" next to each property value. Now for your concern of having multiple modals for each form, it dependes of your layout, you can use one and place it inside your main container or at the end of your html right before the closing body tag, then instead of position absolute, use position fixed, and your modal will be centered in your page, no matter if you scrolled it.